# PHP to convert a string of 20 alphanumeric characters into 10 alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, compression

For work, we'll be given an alphanumeric string of up to 20 characters. I need to find out if I can convert a 20 character string into 10 characters, and be able to reverse it later.

I was thinking of converting the alpha characters into numbers, then dividing by a certain number, say something like 16.8347464849, that would give me a much smaller number. Then going the other way, I could multiply the small number by 16.8347464849 to get my original, but converting the numbers back to letters would be tricky.

Is there a way to do this other than storing a database on my server of the converted values?

Example:
`$string = "8D89A6DF8FG7FG87F87";

$converted = $string / magic; //$converted = "8A0S9872AA";`

Comment: You can make your own "codepage". Upon such codepage, you can assichn numbers to symbols and save these binary. Also, take look at red-black tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that without any other information about the format of the original string. If the input string can have * any * 20 alphanumeric characters, and you are transforming it into 10 alphanumeric characters, there are always several 20 character strings that will output the same 10 character string, making it impossible to revert the transformation.

Comment: Thanks. Logic makes since, but I'm not a math genius, so I thought I'd ask if there was something obvious which I was missing.